# Discord.js edit restart message

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there any way I can edit my message after the bot restarted? I want him to send a message, restarting now and after the restart it should edit the message to Done :white_checkmark:

```js
console.log(message.author.tag + ' restarted The bot')
message.reply('You restarted the bot, wait a few seconds') // <-- this message should be edited
bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send(message.author.tag + ' restarted the bot')
bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send('---------------------------------------------------')
setTimeout(function () { resetBot() }, 5000);


function resetBot() {
    restarted = true;
    bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send('Restarting...')
        .then(msg => bot.destroy())
        .then(() => bot.login(auth.token));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.reply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), resolving with another [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). To use the sent message, you have to access the returned value. Mind the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of `restartMsg` in the examples below.

```js
console.log(`${message.author.tag} restarted the bot.`);

message.reply('You restarted the bot, please wait.')
  .then(restartMsg => {
    const logsChannel = bot.channels.get('593824605144088586');
    if (!logsChannel) return console.error('Logs channel missing.');

    logsChannel.send(`${message.author.tag} restarted the bot.\n---`)
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          logsChannel.send('Restarting...')
            .then(() => bot.destroy())
            .then(() => bot.login(auth.token))
            .then(() => restartMsg.edit('Restart successful.'));
        }, 5000);
      });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

[Async/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) equivalent:

```js
// Asynchronous context (meaning within an async function) needed to use 'await.'

try {
  console.log(`${message.author.tag} restarted the bot.`);

  const restartMsg = await message.reply('You restarted the bot, please wait.');

  const logsChannel = bot.channels.get('593824605144088586');
  if (!logsChannel) return console.error('Logs channel missing.');

  await logsChannel.send(`${message.author.tag} restarted the bot.\n---`);

  setTimeout(async () => {
    await logsChannel.send('Restarting...');

    await bot.destroy();
    await bot.login(auth.token);

    await restartMsg.edit('Restart successful.');
  }, 5000);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```